# What are the beta functions for electroweak and strong constants of interactions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, interactions, physical-constants

As the title says I want to find beta function for electroweak and strong constants ($g$ for W-boson, $g'$ for B-boson and $g_s$ for gluons)

Beta function is the function that describes change in constant of interaction

$\beta(g)=\frac{\partial g}{\partial ln\mu}$

Where $\mu$ is energy scale

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function_(physics)#Examples).

Comment: Thanks, as I can see here is represented QED and general SU(N) beta functions. So, for W-boson I can use SU(2). But for B-boson is the problem. It's described by U(1) symmetry just as QED, but it could be expressed as $\frac{e}{sin(\theta_W)}$. Which of those two methods should I use. P.S. I haven't tried, but they may lead to same result